Is there a way to retrieve the refresh date and time from a Power Query loaded to a table in Excel?
I'm trying to find an exact timestamp for a query to find exactly when a datapoint was updated in my database yesterday (No way to retrieve this otherwise).
By using version history I can narrow it down to a 20 minute period between refreshes, however I can't be sure that the auto-save time corresponds with the refresh time.
When I look at the information for a query refreshed today, I can see the time-stamp so I am thinking that this information must be stored somewhere?
Alternatively, would there be a way to see when the table-object was updated? This could act as a proxy for the query refresh.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!
Query 1 - Refreshed Yesterday, Query 2 - Refreshed Today
I've looked for solutions, and only found advice that suggests adding a reference that takes Date.TodayNow() at the same time as the query refresh. This will be helpful going forward but does not allow me to access historical refresh date-times.

pls check if this is what you want.
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WckksSS3JzE1Vio0FAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Refresh = _t]),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "LastUpdate", each DateTime.LocalNow())
in
    #"Added Custom"


after you refresh the data, the time will change automatically.

Hi, Thank you for your response! Unfortunately, when I add the date-time column, it is populated with the current date-time, not the time of refresh.

The first time is the current datetime. Then when we refresh the time will update to refresh time.
